# Jmeter performance trend report graphs are not visible in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

**Performance Trend report:**

The graphs are empty when I click performance trend

[image]

***But, When I click on the below link it shows below graphs***
[image]

could someone help me in this....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many builds have you run? One? So what "trend" do you expect to see? Try running at least one more and it will be there.

As per [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article:

> On the **first build** with the plugin enabled, **you’ll see empty charts** for the “Performance Trend”.

> **The charts will change as you create more builds.** They will display average, median and 90 percentile values along with the errors count. The charts are clickable, so you can get more detailed information on each executed sampler.

More information:

- [How to Run Test with Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html)
- [How to Build Reports with Peformance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html)